# Should I create a new QDomDocument on the heap?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, qdomdocument

I will load multiple XML files, each into a `QDomDocument`, and then use a `QMap` to associate an identifying string with each document.  Should I store a `QDomDocument` or a pointer to a `QDomDocument` in the map?  i.e., which of the following examples is more in keeping with Qt best design practices.

I suspect that example A is preferred.  All the code samples I see just create a local `QDomDocument` on the stack.  And, `sizeof( QDomDocument )` is 4 bytes;  so, `QDomDocument` is probably a thin wrapper that can be shallow copied without much of a performance hit.

#### A: Map contains `QDomDocument` instances

```
class Core
{
private:
  QMap<QString, QDomDocument> docs;

public:
  Core( void )
  {
    QFile file( "alpha.xml" );
    file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );

    QDomDocument doc;
    doc.setContent( &file );
    docs["alpha"] = doc;

    // ... etc for other XML files
  }

  QString findThing( QString const & docName, QString const & thingName )
  {
    QDomDocument doc = docs[docName];

    // ... search the doc for the thing with the given name
  }
};
```

#### B. Map contains pointers to `QDomDocument` instances

```
class Core
{
private:
  QMap<QString, QDomDocument *> docs;

public:
  Core( void )
  {
    QFile file( "alpha.xml" );
    file.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly );

    QDomDocument * pDoc = new QDomDocument();
    pDoc->setContent( &file );
    docs["alpha"] = pDoc;

    // ... etc for other XML files
  }

  QString findThing( QString const & docName, QString const & thingName )
  {
    QDomDocument * pDoc = docs[docName];

    // ... search the doc for the thing with the given name
  }
};
```

Comment: `QDomDocument * pDoc = new QDomDocument();` -- Did you take in consideration the cost of calling the memory allocator each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP suspicions are quite right: `QDomDocument` holds a pointer to its implementation (PIMPL) through its base class, `QDomNode`.

While [fonZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080633/fonz) is right in saying the original object will go out of scope and destroyed, the copy stored in the map will keep the (shared) implementation alive. Taking a look at [the source](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/xml/dom/qdom.cpp), we see an empty destructor for `QDomDocument`, and  its base class destructor reveals a reference counting mechanism:

```
QDomNode::~QDomNode()
{
    if (impl && !impl->ref.deref())
        delete impl;
}
```

the count gets incremented in copy construction:

```
QDomNode::QDomNode(const QDomNode &n)
{
    impl = n.impl;
    if (impl)
        impl->ref.ref();
}
```

and in assignment as well:

```
QDomNode& QDomNode::operator=(const QDomNode &n)
{
    if (n.impl)
        n.impl->ref.ref();
    if (impl && !impl->ref.deref())
        delete impl;
    impl = n.impl;
    return *this;
}
```

thus method *A* is legal and safe, and bears no memory handling concerns.

I would also point out that using `QMap::insert` instead of the subscript operator is a bit more performant.

Doing:

```
QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent( &file );
docs["alpha"] = doc;
```

or

```
docs["alpha"] = QDomDocument();
docs["alpha"].setContent( &file );
```

will both produce this:

- a `QDomDocument` object is created (a temporary, in the second snippet)
- another `QDomDocument` object is created (inside the map) calling `docs["alpha"]`
- the latter is assigned to the first.

Using

```
docs.insert("alpha", QDomDocument());
docs["alpha"].setContent( &file );
```

will only call the temporary constructor and the map item copy-constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's very clear that your QDomDocument is deleted when the scope ends:

```
{ // scope starts here 
    // create document on the stack
    QDomDocument doc;
    ...
    docs["alpha"] = doc;
} // scope ends here, stack is cleaned, doc is deleted
```

Creating QDomDocument on the heap solves the problem but might not be the best solution. For example, this should also work fine:

```
{
    ...
    docs["alpha"] = QDomDocument();
    docs["alpha"].setContent( &file );
    ...    
}
```

Comment: Good catch, @fonZ.  Thanks.

Comment: @fonZ take a look at my (edited) answer (both ways work, but there's a better third way ...)